# Weird Shading Issue

Tags: shaders

While modelling a human body, i've noticed some faces have a weird shading, the normals are facing front, i have no idea what has gone wrong, i'm using blender 2.79[image: Red outline shows the issue] Let me know if you need the file!

FILE:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/623576718812119089/717098659543777321/girlbase.blend

Comment: Yeah, I think the file might be helpful. It's pretty hard to tell what's going on from the photo.

Comment: how can i send you the file?

Comment: Go to - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ - upload the .blend file, paste in the URL of this question where it says and upload.

Comment: just added a discord download file, it should work haha

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Well, so far I can confirm that the normals under the armpit area and the ones on the back are pointing 180 degrees the opposite direction of the normals on the front. I'm trying to figure out how to set them best,

Comment: alright, also if it helps, when you disable de mirror modifier and enter edit mode it looks fine

Answer (score 2):

Just apply the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> , I see the file

Comment: Thanks man you're the bast!!!

Comment: Confirmed, non uniform scale was the problem

Comment: @user97922 Hello and welcome. Please don't add thank you as an answer, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted